# Unable to load assets in single spa angular application

Tags: angular, single-spa, single-spa-angular

I'm working with a single-spa-angular setup where my main application (app1) is running on port `4200` and a child application (app2) is on port `4201`. Both applications are built using `Angular 13`. I'm encountering an issue where asset requests for app2 are mistakenly being sent to app1's port (`4200`), resulting in 404 errors.

In app2, when I use a CSS property like `background-image: url('assets/abc.svg')`, the request is wrongly directed to port 4200 instead of 4201. This is happening despite having the assets correctly configured in angular.json.

- Following the single-spa official [documentation](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/ecosystem-angular/#angular-assets), which suggests using
  assetUrl for loading assets in HTML and TypeScript, but it doesn't
  cover CSS.
- Setting `__webpack_public_path__`, but this did not resolve the issue.
- Considering the `--deploy-url` option, but it's deprecated in Angular
  13.

Has anyone faced a similar issue in a single-spa-angular environment, particularly with Angular 13? Any suggestions or solutions on how to ensure CSS asset requests are directed to the correct port would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please validate the base href, You need to set it to the sub application routing

Comment: did you check if the paths are set correctly in each Angular app angular.json file? Specifically under "assets" array,

Comment: @ThuanTran yes, I can see the svg if I hit localhost:4201/path_to_svg.